# Extend jQuery UI Icons with Font-Awesome

Tags: jquery-ui, font-awesome

I want a way to extend the default jQuery UI icons with Font-Awesome icons.  If possible keep the jQuery icons as a fallback, since Font-Awesome doesn't have full coverage.

jQuery UI Example:

```
$("#muteAll").button({
    text: false, 
    icons: { 
        primary: "ui-icon-volume-on" 
    }
});
```

Font-Awesome Replacement/Extended Example:

```
$("#muteAll").button({
    text: false, 
    icons: { 
        primary: "icon-volume-up" 
    }
});
```

The closest I have come up with is:

```
.ui-icon[class*=" icon-"] {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 1px; 
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any icons. If you mean jQuery **UI** icons, sure, of course you can replace them. You have all the CSS. Or you could just replace the files without changing the CSS.

Comment: you are right.  I'll update my question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Final solution for stock jQuery with annotations that I've come up with:

```
/* Allow Font Awesome Icons in lieu of jQuery UI and only apply when using a FA icon */
.ui-icon[class*=" icon-"] {
    /* Remove the jQuery UI Icon */
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    /* Remove the jQuery UI Text Indent */
    text-indent: 0; 
    /* Bump it up - jQuery UI is -8px */
    margin-top: -0.5em;
}

/* Allow use of icon-large to be properly aligned */
.ui-icon.icon-large {
    margin-top: -0.75em;
}

.ui-button-icon-only .ui-icon[class*=" icon-"] {
    /* Bump it - jQuery UI is -8px */
    margin-left: -7px;
}
```

Demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brombomb/PywSW/)

Answer (score 12):

Here is @Brombomb's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493936/22399) but for FontAwesome 4.x icons:

```
/* Allow Font Awesome Icons in lieu of jQuery UI and only apply when using a FA icon */
.ui-icon[class*=" fa-"] {
    /* Remove the jQuery UI Icon */
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    /* Remove the jQuery UI Text Indent */
    text-indent: 0; 
    /* Bump it up - jQuery UI is -8px */
    margin-top: -0.5em;
}

/* Allow use of icon-large to be properly aligned */
.ui-icon.icon-large {
    margin-top: -0.75em;
}

.ui-button-icon-only .ui-icon[class*=" fa-"] {
    /* Bump it - jQuery UI is -8px */
    margin-left: -7px;
}
```

Comment: the difference is fontawesome has changed their prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://www.dotcastle.com/blog/font-awesome-icons-for-jquery-mobile

- Based on the latest jQuery Mobile and Font Awesome frameworks, updated when any of these frameworks update
- Icons based on SVG vector paths from the original Font Awesome kit
- PNG fallbacks for browsers without SVG support
- Four versions of the CSS files with two options for each format (SVG & PNG)
- You can use inline version or url version of the resources based on your requirements

Comment: Link has problem, can you check it, please?