# change jquery ui images to icon

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, zurb-foundation

In my app I am using Jquery ui. I think that most of the plugins in Jquery ui uses a lot of images. Like for date picker, the next and previous icons are images. I was thinking of changing those images to icons. I am using Foundation and trying to change those images with icons from Foundation.

In the css file I have found this

```
.ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(/Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsContent}*/; }
```

Is there and easy and elegant way to use Foundation icons instead of these images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider to use an image to font replacement css hack.

I have done a similar job using fontawesome, with foundation can be similar:

```
 /* Allow Font Awesome Icons in lieu of jQuery UI and only apply when using a FA icon */
.ui-icon[class*=" icon-"] {
    /* Remove the jQuery UI Icon */
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    /* Remove the jQuery UI Text Indent */
    text-indent: 0;
    /* Bump it up - jQuery UI is -8px */
    margin-top: -0.5em;
}

.ui-button-icon-only .ui-icon[class*=" icon-"] {
    /* Bump it - jQuery UI is -8px */
    margin-left: -7px;
}

/* Allow use of icon-large to be properly aligned */
.ui-icon.icon-large {
    margin-top: -0.75em;
}
```

Similar question on Fontawesome: [How to use the bigger jQuery icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696085/how-to-use-the-bigger-jquery-icons/18697126#18697126)