# jQuery UI with Font Awesome undesired effect (with jQuery 3.2.1 )

Tags: jquery-ui, font-awesome

In order to use jQuery UI with Font Awesome icons, I followed the suggestions
given by @Brombomb and @Clever in [Extend jQuery UI Icons with Font-Awesome.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459115/extend-jquery-ui-icons-with-font-awesome)

Nevertheless, when using jQuery 3.2.1, an undesired effect is shown when hovering above the buttons: a small caret character is displayed underneath the icon.

You can see it in this simplified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/R_Caruso/g80ne1h7/) example.

```js
// Font Awesome Icons
$('#btn1').button({icon: 'fa fa-save'});
$('#btn2').button({icon: 'fa fa-trash'});
$('#btn3').button({icon: 'fa fa-undo'});
```

```css
 /* Allow Font Awesome Icons in lieu of jQuery UI and only apply when using a FA icon */
.ui-icon[class*=" fa-"] {
    /* Remove the jQuery UI Icon */
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    /* Remove the jQuery UI Text Indent */
    text-indent: 0;    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<h4>Replacing / Extending jQuery UI with Font Awesome</h4>


<div id="btn1">Save</div>
<div id="btn2">Delete</div>
<div id="btn3">Cancel</div>
```

Is there a way to get rid of this undesired effect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule in the CSS. Make sure you namespace it properly:

```
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon,
.ui-state-focus .ui-icon,
.ui-button:hover .ui-icon,
.ui-button:focus .ui-icon {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/g80ne1h7/13/